# Error while building libtensorflow.so on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, tensorflow, go, bazel

**Problem Statement:** I would like to use Golang TensorFlow to run my model in Raspberry PI 3. To use TensorFlow go, I need to have ***libtensorflow.so*** and ***libtensorflow_framework.so*** c++ shared library.

I was trying to build from source using **bazel v0.20.0** but facing a problem and its erroring out at last.

**Goal:** **Build libtensorflow.so for tensorflow r1.11.0 or r1.12.0**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please take a look around https://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to make the minimal, complete, and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This community is willing to help you. Therefore, consider updating your question sharing more insights.

Comment: you should show the error at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
I found solution:
Couple of things to take care.

***For Tensorflow < v1.5***
Follow instruction here: https://blog.meinside.pe.kr/TensorFlow-and-Go-on-Raspberry-Pi/

***For Tensorflow v1.11.0 - v1.12.0***
Install bazel:
1. Download bazel from link: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases
for specific architecture.
2. Install bazel
chmod +x bazel-<version>-installer-linux-<arch>.sh
./bazel-<version>-installer-linux-<arch>.sh --user
Install protobuf:
1. Build/Install protobuf from source.
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md
Build Tensorflow:
1. Git clone
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
2. Check and remove build from specific tensorflow version
go to: tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/*_toolchain.sh [specific to your linux type and arch]
remove the bazel build and installation like as follows
look for the line: **rm -rf /usr/local/bin/bazel** and remove
and remove **bazel** from line **apt-get install -y ...**

then run 
CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS="-e CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 -e CROSSTOOL_PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.6" tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh

or 

tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh 

or 

tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh PI_ONE

Output:
Output can be found here:
output-artifacts
output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl
output-artifacts/libtensorflow_framework.so
output-artifacts/benchmark_model
output-artifacts/libtensorflow.so

Dependency Versions:
Tensorflow       Bazel       protoc
<1.5             0.5.0       3.0 <any>
1.11.0-1.12.0    0.15.2      3.x <any>
>1.12.0          new vers    <any>
```